# JavaScript Image Slider in Oracle_ADF 12.2.1

Tags: javascript, html, css, oracle, oracle-adf

I am trying to implement an animated Image Slider(using HTML) on my website homepage using Oracle-ADF 12.2.1 . The javascript I am using renders the properties in the initial page load but when I navigate back to the page the animation disappears. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

"when I navigate back to the page the animation disappears”
Presumly you are using an “af:button” to navigate back to your page.
Try adding partialSubmit=“false” to that button. It will reload the entire page, therfore it will act as if you open the page for the first time.

Comment: We are using panelTab af:panelTabbed option... Is there any similar option for this ?

Comment: You can attach a clientListener (a javascript call) to your showDetailItem.
You can find a similar concept, below :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/104-interceptpaneltabswitching-1880961.pdf